# auto complete on editable divs angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am not able to perform the auto suggestion functionality on divs with contenteditable attribute. Also when I write mass-autocomplete to divs, it is showing an error message like "mass-autocomplete not allowed on element div".

The following is code I have written. Could you please give the solution for this?

```js
$scope.getClients = {
  suggest: suggest_Client
};
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="marginTB15" mass-autocomplete>
      <div class="reach_box" contenteditable="true" ng-model="user.communities" mass-autocomplete-item="getNetworks">
        <span class="form-control-feedback form-control-feedback_left_textbox"><img src="images/icon7.png" ></span>
        <div class="reach"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you using the mass-autocomplete directive incorrectly, it need so have an `<input>` tag as a element. Consider just having 2 blocks inside your div - one is a normal autocomplete:

```
<div mass-autocomplete>
  <input ng-model="user.communities" mass-autocomplete-item="getNetworks">
</div>
```

while another one is a static end result of the autocompletion - say `<div>{{user.communities}}</div>`. And those two will be toggled by click for example. By this you wont' need content-editable at all.

So full code may look like this:

```
//controller
$scope.stateEdit = false;
$scope.toggleWidgetState = function(){
  $scope.stateEdit = !$scope.stateEdit;
}
$scope.getClients = {
  suggest: suggest_Client,
  on_select:toggleWidgetState  //here we put our widget back to read-only state
};
//other logic to handle mass-autocomplete

//template
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
  <div mass-autocomplete ng-show="stateEdit">
    <input ng-model="user.communities" mass-autocomplete-item="getNetworks">
 <ul> <li>Cardiologist Connect<button type="button">X</button></li></ul>
      </div>
      <div ng-show="!stateEdit" ng-click="toggleWidgetState()">
      {{getNetworks}}
        <span class="form-control-feedback form-control-feedback_left_textbox"><img src="images/icon7.png" ></span>
        <div class="reach"></div>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Here I do not want to use input field. I want to perform mass-autocomplete-item on div only. The reason to use this is i have to insert below html code inside the div area.Could you please look on this.                                                               <ul>
                  <li>Cardiologist Connect<button type="button">X</button></li>
                  </ul>

Comment: why "I want to perform mass-autocomplete-item on div only" ? you can style <input> same way as <div> with CSS. Anyway  if you stuck to use <div> then you won't be able to use mass-autocomplete plugin

Comment: Is it possible to insert the below html code in input fields after auto suggestion functionality .  <ul> <li>Cardiologist Connect<button type="button">X</button></li> </ul>

Comment: put it into teh <div> that is wrapping tou inpout, check my upodated answer

Comment: I am getting following error in html view page. "Attribute massautocomplete is not allowed on element div at this point". Give me the solution where to put that attribute.

Comment: I think it's getting nowhere with guessing. please consider creating a working example reproducing the problem on https://jsfiddle.net or http://plnkr.co/ - with you html, js and libraries included, then we can take a look again